# Calculation involving complex numbers and modules

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been racking my brain about the following for an hour now, to no avail… Can anyone help out, or at least tell me the first couple of steps in resolving this?

$z$ is a complex number and $n \geq 1$ is a natural number. It is given that |z|=2. Calculate the number $α=|z^n+\overline z^n|^2+|z^n-\overline z^n|^2$.

Thank you!

Comment: Those seem reminiscent of the hyperbolic trig functions cosh and sinh. Have you tried something in that direction?

Comment: Looks more like the ordinary trig functions to me, @Fede.

Comment: Yes, that’s what was on my mind. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @FedePoncio
Yes, the trig functions should be the idea, but I simply cannot work it out...

Comment: Let $z=2e^{i\theta}$. Can you express $z^n+{\overline z}^n$ in terms of trig functions, dalta? If you can express $e^{ix}$ in terms of trig functions, and if you're familiar with de Moivre's formula, you should be able to do that (and if not, well, now you know what you have to learn).

Comment: @GerryMyerson
Thank you, Gerry! I know the trig functions and de Moivre's formula, so I will give it a go in a minute. However, important question so that I learn: how did it occur to you to use $2e^{iθ}$? Why that number and not another?

Comment: @dalta it’s beacause $|z|=2$, so in polar coordinates then, $r=2$